# JPanel is not visible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, menuitem

I am trying use JMenuItem to remove and add the panels I need.  However, when ever I use the action listener and I tell it to add a panel, nothing happens.

```
PanelMaker newPanel = new Panel(); //I have my panel in another class and I use this to call it
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       add(newPanel.pane());//I try to add the panel here, but nothing occurs
    }
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, for anyone who is dealing with the same problem, you need to add  "revalidate();"  Which I am assuming refreshes the JFrame

Comment: @user2059856: no not quite. Please see my answer. And don't forget `repaint()`, especially if you remove components. Else you're in for bad surprises.

Answer (score 3):

You need to revalidate and repaint the container that gets components added or removed. i.e.,

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    add(newPanel.pane());//I try to add the panel here, but nothing occurs
    revalidate(); // tells the layout managers to re-layout components
    repaint();  // requests that the repaint manager repaint the container
}
```

The call to `revalidate()` tells the container's layout manager to re-layout all components held by it, and likewise can cause a cascade of re-layouts of all contained containers.

The call to `repaint()` again suggests to the repaint manager to repaint the container and all of its children. This is important especially if components are removed or if components move on top of a location where another component was previously seen, in order to clean up old renderings.

Also very important is the layout manager used by the container. Some don't readily accept new components easily -- GroupLayout comes to mind immediately in this regard.